# Vbscript Sendkeys not working in some applications

Tags: vbscript, automation, windows-10, window, sendkeys

I recently google around and found that tools like [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download/standard) can be automated to Scan and Fix Regsitry errors by VBScript or AutoIt scripts.

As I prefer native tools and libraries, so I created a VBScript to automate the Registry Cleaning process(not upto the last button click, as there are too many buttons for that to be automatable), which is as below:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set UsrEnvDmn = WshShell.Environment("User")
UsrEnvDmn("CclnrInstDir") = "C:\Program Files\CCleaner"
WshShell.Run """%CclnrInstDir%\\CCleaner64.exe"" /Registry"
WScript.Sleep 1000 : WshShell.AppActivate "CCleaner"
WScript.Sleep 2000 : WshShell.SendKeys "%s"
WScript.Sleep 5000 : WshShell.SendKeys "%f"
Set WshShell = Nothing : Set UsrEnvDmn = Nothing
```

But the problem is once CCLeaner opens and comes into focus, the `Sendkeys` function isn't clicking/selecting any buttons or options in the window. If I press manually `Alt + s` then the Scan process indeed starts, but I badly need to automate that thing, if possible upto the very end of registry cleanup process.

Can anyone guide on this ?

Comment: Also type `cleanmgr /?` as both a user an as an admin. This is the only safe way.

Answer (score 0):

See the remarks section of [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow). Your script has to comply with at least one of those rules when you use `AppActivate` (as this is what `AppActivate` calls). You keep sleeping and losing the right to set the foreground window. See CCleaner documentation on a better way https://www.ccleaner.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A
>   process can set the foreground window only if one of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> •The process is the foreground process.
>
> •The process was started by the foreground process.
>
> •The process received the last input event.
>
> •There is no foreground process.
>
> •The process is being debugged.
>
> •The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start
>   Screen.
>
> •The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
>
> •The foreground lock time-out has expired (see
>   SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
>
> •No menus are active.

Comment: Pal, firstly you shared the link of CCleaner Command Line parameters, in which page, *there isn't any SetForegroundWindow* section, secondly, I checked the other links in that manual already as well, but none of links say anything about any rules of using AppActivate with CCleaner, so I don't know what documentation you're talking about, but that CCLeaner documentation surely doesn't have it... Put the links that provides insight on VBscript function AppActivate...

Comment: A long, long time ago programs could set the foreground window without restrictions. So programs abused it or were so slow starting up the user got bored and started doing something else, then a windows pops up annoying the user. So rules started being applied to stop programs stealing the focus.

Comment: Also you cannot `sendkeys` to a more privileged applications. This was bought in in Windows Vista to prevent script pretending to be admins by sending keys to a program running as admin.